# Unable to read the dynamic array property using KQL

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I have below structure json object

```
{
 "records": [
   {
     "key": "be4kf29j",
     "value": {
       "channelId": "Connect"
     }
   }
 ]
```

}

I am trying to retrieve all the key values. Below is the KQL query i am using. but i am unbale retrieve the "key" field values.

```
   let js = '{"records":[{"key":"be4kf29j","value":{"channelId":"Connect"}}]}';
let recs = parse_json(js);
recs
| mv-expand dd = recs.records
| extend key = tostring(dd.key)
```

Can somebody guide me what i am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [parse_json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction) does take a bit of getting used to.

In your particular cases the following worked for me.

```
let js = '{"records":[{"key":"be4kf29j","value":{"channelId":"Connect"}}]}';
let recs = parse_json(js);
print recs = parse_json(js), parse_json(js)['records'], parse_json(tostring(parse_json(parse_json(js)['records'])))[0]['key']
```

| recs | print_1 | print_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| {"records":[{"key":"be4kf29j","value":{"channelId":"Connect"}}]} | [{"key":"be4kf29j","value":{"channelId":"Connect"}}] | be4kf29j |

Of if you're using it from a table something like this should work.

```
let T = datatable (recs:string) [
'{"records":[{"key":"be4kf29j","value":{"channelId":"Connect"}}]}'
];
T
| extend jsonrecs = parse_json(recs)
| extend records = jsonrecs['records']
| extend keyvalue = parse_json(tostring(records))[0]['key']
```

| recs | jsonrecs | records | keyvalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"records":[{"key":"be4kf29j","value":{"channelId":"Connect"}}]} | {"records":[{"key":"be4kf29j","value":{"channelId":"Connect"}}]} | [{"key":"be4kf29j","value":{"channelId":"Connect"}}] | be4kf29j |